# remove image element based on source

Tags: javascript, regex, windows-8

How can I use vanilla javascript + regEx to remove image elements, based on their source?

I am reading a RSS feed with a web app. I want to remove certain image elements if their source contains the word "comments".

It would be ideal to edit the rss feed before it's rendered onto the page (just pulled from the http request, and still in a 'string').

update:
Thanks for the replies. At the very bottom of each article, they are including a link to comments... which is what I want to remove.
Here is the code at the very end of each article:

`<a rel="nofollow" href="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/ADDRESS/FEED"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/comments/[ADDRESS]/[FEED]" /></a>`

also, the [feed] value changes per article. So would it be better to check for the word 'comments' or check if the source starts with x?

Comment: An XML parser would probably work better than RegEx and the performance would certainly be better. However, if you want to use RegEx, post small sample of the RSS feed and I'll write one.

Comment: What do you mean their source code contains the word "comments"? What part of the source? I would assume an attribute, so which one? And there's no need for a regex to do this.

Comment: @user1689607 `<img src="` <<< this kind of source is meant

Comment: Thanks for the replies. At the very bottom of each article, they are including a link to comments... which is what I want to remove.
Here is the code at the very end of each article:

<a rel="nofollow" href="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/ADDRESS/FEED"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/comments/[ADDRESS]/[FEED]" /></a>

Comment: I'd say " rewrite `$('img[src*="comments"]').remove()` to vanilla".

Comment: So... do you want to delete `an image whose src contains` (title), or `a link whose href contains` (an intermediate conclusion of mine), or `a link which contains an image whose src contains` (my current guess)?

Answer (score 2):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i];
    if (img.src.indexOf('comments') > 0) {
       var link = img.parentNode;
       link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```

- line 1: get a list of all images elements on the page
- line 2: iterate over the list, remove those who's src has the word 'comments'. This is done by calling the `indexOf` method of any string object. [Detailed here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Comment: updated: I made a small mistake in the previous answer. now fixed.

Comment: Note: this will remove the _image_. The question currently seems to ask how to remove its _parent_.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. You're code needed a bit of tweaking, but this works. Instead of removing the parent OR image (that threw exceptions), I've simply hidden the element

`
        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var img = images[i];
            if (img.src.indexOf('comments') > 0) {
                img.style.display = "none";
            }
        }`

Comment: @BobSmith Glad to hear it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
var imgs=document.images;
for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)
    if(imgs[i].src.test('comments'))
        imgs[i].parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(imgs[i].parentNode);​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPRhL/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. lins05 suggested some code that i've adjusted slightly. Note: instead of removing the element or it's parent, the following code simply hides the element.

```
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var img = images[i];
        if (img.src.indexOf('comments') > 0) {
            img.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

The rss feed's list of articles are stored in a model on the page. It would be more ideal to chop the comments out of the model.. however the current approach of 'hiding the element every time the article is on the page' works fine :)